# jQuery don't run in WordPress backend until post is published

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, backend

I'm writing a plugin for WordPress, and I'm using a custom post type created by the plugin.

I've added some jQuery to the post editing page. When I wrote it I was looking at a published post, and all works fine.

But when I tried to create a new post, I noticed that jQuery was not working anymore.

After some tests, I noticed that jQuery completely don't run if the post is not published.

I'd tried to run this simple code`console.log('jQuery is running');` but nothing append on unpublished post (new posts).

Have an idea on what is appening?

UPDATE:
I there is something wrong in the way I enqueue the script.

This is how actually i enqueue my script

```
function enqueue_scripts_back_end($hook) {
if ( 'post.php' != $hook || 'post-new.php' != $hook) {
    return;
}

wp_enqueue_script( 'aws_app_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app.js' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_back_end' );
```

I need to apply my code to the post-new.php page, here is not working

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was on the right way and finally I solved!

The problem was on the condition || (or), cause after 5 hours of coding I was a little confusing.

Since I want my jQuery run on the post-new.php and post.php the condition is ovviously && (and), so the correct enqueue is this one.

```
function enqueue_scripts_back_end($hook) {
if ( 'post.php' != $hook && 'post-new.php' != $hook) {
    return;
}

wp_enqueue_script( 'aws_app_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'app.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_back_end' );
```

Thanks!